# Why does the metabox display?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

Strange question : I wonder why something works :)

I tested this piece of code on my remote website (where I have defined a custom post type named `bateau`).

It works perfectly, but I wonder why : I haven't installed the CMB library, and as far as I know I don't have any plugin that uses this library (I tried to shut them down though, but this code is still working).

In other words, for an unknown reason, the `cmb_meta_boxes` filter is known.

What mechanism creates the custom metabox ? I don't see any `add_meta_box()` in this code.

```
function bateau_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {
        $prefix = ""; // Prefix for all fields
        $meta_boxes['bateau_metabox'] = array(
            'id' => 'bateau_metabox',
            'title' => 'Saisir les informations sur le bateau :',
            'pages' => array('bateau'), // post type
            'context' => 'normal',
            'priority' => 'high',
            'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
            'fields' => array(

                array(
                    'name' => 'Nom du bateau :',
                    'id' => $prefix . 'bateau_nom',
                    'desc' => 'Nom du bateau tel qu\'il est écrit dans le titre ci-dessus',
                    'type' => 'text'
                    ),  

            ),
        );

        return $meta_boxes;
    }

    add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'bateau_metaboxes' );
```

Note : the same code as above does not display the metabox on a local WP site.

Answer (score 0):

Solved : the theme I run on the remote website uses the CMB library !